# No border color in "pheatmap" in R

Tags: r, pheatmap

I am exploring R to analyze my gene expression data.

I could create a pretty heatmap using the `pheatmap` package. However, while transitioning between different colored boxes, it automatically introduces a border color which I can see after zooming in. This is in spite of adding the attribute `border_color = "NA"`. Is it possible to get continuously varying heatmap? Thanks.

My code:

```
 pheatmapM <-pheatmap(datExprM, border_color = "NA", breaks = NULL, color = colorRampPalette(c("navy", "black", "yellow"))(50), cluster_rows = TRUE, cluster_cols = TRUE, scale = "row")
```

[image: My heatmap]

As you can see below (after zooming), the neighboring boxes are separated by lighter colors.

[image: Zoomed heatmap with lighter borders]

Comment: Try `border_color = NA` without quotes around the NA ?

Comment: Already tried, doesn't work.

Comment: Both `border_color = NA` and `border_color = "NA"` work perfectly fine to me

Comment: Actually it worked on the Windows computer but didn't work on my Mac. Quite strange.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Did you ever figure it out? I am even editing the svg file, and for some reason svg renderers still show the border with stroke attribute set to none.

Comment: Observation: So I actually came here because my borders weren't showing up, when making a png in windows these lines are not present and become visible when writing the image as an svg. How unusual.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the border colours individually for each cell, which can be used to solve this. The exact solution will depend on the exact composition of your `pheatmap` object.

First, get the names of grobs (graphical objects) stored in your heatmap. You will need to grab the one which corresponds to the individual rectangles (cells) of the heatmap. For me, this is the first grob of class `gTree`, but try and see which one works for you. This is how I extract the name of the grob:

```
grob_classes <- purrr::map(pheatmapM$gtable$grobs, class)
idx_grob <- which(purrr::map_lgl(grob_classes, function(cl) 'gTree' %in% cl))[1]
```

Next, we need to find a rectangle grob that is a child of the `gTree` grob we've just found, like this:

```
grob_names <- names(pheatmapM$gtable$grobs[[idx_grob]]$children)
idx_rect <- grob_names[grep('rect', grob_names)][1]
```

Now, from this nested grob you can extract graphical parameters: `fill` (which determines the actual fill colour of each cell) and `col` (which determines border colour). By default, `col` is a single value whereas `fill` is a matrix of hex codes. When I replace `col` with what is stored in `fill`, like this...

```
pheatmapM$gtable$grobs[[idx_grob]]$children[[idx_rect]]$gp$col <- pheatmapM$gtable$grobs[[idx_grob]]$children[[idx_rect]]$gp$fill
```

...that amounts to eliminating the border, since it's now the same colour as the fill. To make extra-sure that no gaps between the cells remain, increase the border thickness as well.

```
pheatmapM$gtable$grobs[[idx_grob]]$children[[idx_rect]]$gp$lwd <- 3
```

---

In my estimation, potential problems might arise with identifying the correct `idx_grob` or `idx_rect` in your particular `pheatmap`. For that reason, I include a reproducible example (with `R 4.0.3` and `pheatmap 1.0.12` running on macOS) that achieves the desired result (no borders as well as no gaps in between the cells) that you can use to start off:

```
set.seed(1)

## Generate sample data
x <- table(round(rnorm(500, 100, 2)), round(rnorm(500, 100, 2)))
ph <- pheatmap::pheatmap(x, cluster_cols = FALSE, cluster_rows = FALSE)

## Extract the right grob
grob_classes <- purrr::map(ph$gtable$grobs, class)
idx_grob <- which(purrr::map_lgl(grob_classes, function(cl) 'gTree' %in% cl))[1]
grob_names <- names(ph$gtable$grobs[[idx_grob]]$children)
idx_rect <- grob_names[grep('rect', grob_names)][1]

## Remove borders around cells
ph$gtable$grobs[[idx_grob]]$children[[idx_rect]]$gp$col <- ph$gtable$grobs[[idx_grob]]$children[[idx_rect]]$gp$fill
ph$gtable$grobs[[idx_grob]]$children[[idx_rect]]$gp$lwd <- 3

## Plot result
graphics::plot.new()
print(ph)
```

The result should look like this:

[image]